# Postgres parent - child network id

Tags: sql, postgresql, graph-theory

I need to calculate the network of interdependent objects. For every E-C link i need additional column that is "unique network id" those objects belong to. Example is from finance industry where loans are linked to objects they finance.

```
create table ec (
    e varchar(10),
    c varchar(10)
);

insert into ec values ('E1','C1');
insert into ec values ('E1','C2');
insert into ec values ('E1','C3');
insert into ec values ('E2','C3');
insert into ec values ('E3','C3');
insert into ec values ('E3','C4');
insert into ec values ('E4','C5');
insert into ec values ('E4','C6');
```

And output should be one of the following:

```
+--------+--------+------------+
| EXP_ID | CRM_ID | NETWORK_ID |
+--------+--------+------------+
| E1     | C1     |          1 |
| E1     | C2     |          1 |
| E1     | C3     |          1 |
| E2     | C3     |          1 |
| E3     | C3     |          1 |
| E3     | C4     |          1 |
| E4     | C5     |          2 |
| E4     | C6     |          2 |
+--------+--------+------------+
```

Or:

```
+----+------------+
| ID | NETWORK_ID |
+----+------------+
| E1 |          1 |
| E1 |          1 |
| E1 |          1 |
| E2 |          1 |
| E3 |          1 |
| E3 |          1 |
| C1 |          1 |
| C2 |          1 |
| C3 |          1 |
| C3 |          1 |
| C3 |          1 |
| C4 |          1 |
| E4 |          2 |
| C5 |          2 |
| C6 |          2 |
+----+------------+
```

Visual connections can be seen like this:

[image]

I've been looking into recursive queries, but im not sure if this is the right way to go.
So, is recursive queries a way to achieve this and i should give it a bit more thought? Or there is something else like graph analysis needed?

Comment: So you're looking to find the [connected components](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Component_(graph_theory)) of a bipartite graph? I suspect this is trivially solved with a graph algorithm but rather hard (though not impossible) in SQL.

Comment: yes, exactly this. i need to find connected components from a huge list of pairs of connected vertices.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, recursive queries can achieve this. Here's a proof of concept that does compute the transitive set of reachable edges (i.e. all edges in the network) for each edge, keyed by an id given to the edge, and then takes the smallest (id of the) edge as a representative for the network, for each edge:

```
WITH RECURSIVE eci AS (
  SELECT row_number() OVER () AS id, * FROM ec
),
networks AS (
  SELECT * FROM eci
UNION
  SELECT LEAST(eci.id, n.id), eci.e, eci.c FROM eci JOIN networks n ON n.e = eci.e OR n.c = eci.c
)
SELECT min(id), ec.e, ec.c FROM ec JOIN networks USING (e, c) GROUP BY e, c;
```

<sup>([dbfiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=64430186ae29c764ada962506b4fabb2))</sup>

Disclaimer: I doubt this is efficient. I have tried but failed to prune the `networks` during the recursion.

Comment: thanks, this gives results as wanted. will test it on 100k+ rows dataset.

Answer (score 0):

I've been toying with different ideas in an attempt to reduce the work needed across large networks.

I played with arrays, I was blocked by Recurives CTEs not allowing aggregation or mutliple references to the recursive expression *(No joining the CTE to itself)*.

My current 'best' attempt seeks to approach the problem as recursively combining sets.  Where a set is combined in to another set if:

- The two sets share a member *(`c`)*
- The 'other' set has a 'lower' identifier

This, I hope, means that the worst case scenario is a binary pattern; 1024 rows would need at most a recursion depth of 10 *(1024 sets become 512, become 256, etc)*.

The reason I was thinking about this is that the anser from @Bergi has a worst case of needing a recursion depth of 1023 for 1024 nodes.

Conversly, however, my approach ends up needing *(I think)* more effort for each iteration.  I'd be intrueged as to which performs better over larger datasets.

- ***I am not saying Bergi's is bad***
- ***I am not saying mine is better***
- ***I'm only saying that they're different***

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=b77940437835bb839ea3c92b05b686e9

```
WITH RECURSIVE
  groups AS
(
  SELECT
    e,
    c,
    DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY e) AS group_id,
    0                              AS search_depth,
    COUNT(*) OVER ()               AS total_changes
  FROM
    ec

  UNION ALL

  SELECT
    e,
    c,
    new_group_id               AS group_id,
    search_depth + 1           AS search_depth,
    SUM(has_changed) OVER ()   AS total_changes
  FROM
  (
    SELECT
      e, c, group_id, search_depth, new_group_id,
      CASE WHEN group_id = new_group_id THEN 0 ELSE 1 END  AS has_changed
    FROM
    (
      SELECT
        e, c, group_id, search_depth,
        MIN(new_group_id) OVER (PARTITION BY group_id) AS new_group_id
      FROM
      (
        SELECT
          e, c, group_id, search_depth,
          MIN(group_id) OVER (PARTITION BY c) AS new_group_id
        FROM
          groups
        WHERE
          total_changes > 0
      )
        combine_by_c
    )
      combine_by_group
  )
    tally_changes
)
SELECT * FROM groups WHERE total_changes = 0
```

***EDIT:***

Plus two attempts identifying groups that can't possibly grow any further, and excluding them from futher iterations.

Depnding on the profile of the data this may take more effort than it saves (most groups require similiar recursion depths), or it might help (large variation in recursion depth required)...

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=0710b63cb39fe92e08156a486c5f2216

Comment: @bergi - I'd be interested in your opinion on this approach?

Comment: "*I was blocked by Recursive CTEs not allowing aggregation or multiple references to the recursive expression*" - same here, I was trying to use these as well :-) I guess you'll need to actually benchmark them, there's no other way to know.